# WPF Get ColumnSpan of an element

Tags: wpf, grid, columnspan

It's really easy to set column span for an UIElement in a grid.

```
Grid.SetColumnSpan(extBorder, gridFormular.ColumnDefinitions.Count());
```

but what's about reading an element's ColumnSpan? **How to do that?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`FrameworkElement.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue.aspx) on the [dependency property identifier for the column span](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616550.aspx):

```
var columnSpan = (int)extBorder.GetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty);
```

This same strategy works for retrieving the value of any dependency property which exists on the element.

Comment: Blazing fast. Thank you so much.

Comment: +1 Not to forget Grid.GetColumnSpan (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.getcolumnspan.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Besides of using GetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty) as shown by sixlettervariables, you also can use [Grid.GetColumnSpan()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.getcolumnspan.aspx).

Comment: +1, for the simple answer. For whatever reason I thought there wasn't one :)